# How to restrict product access to personal user uploads in WordPress

Tags: uploads, production

By default, WordPress allows authors to see all products on all products on your site. If you invite a large number of guest writers, this can be problematic. How to restrict access to all WordPress products to the user's own uploads?

Comment: WordPress does not come with a products post type, is this a WooCommerce question?

Comment: In the WordPress dashboard, I mean the products section - all products

Comment: like I said, there is no products section in standard WordPress, only posts and pages, if you are seeing a product section it's because something else added it, did you create this with a CPT/custom plugin? Or did you install an ecommerce plugin such as WooCommerce? It's not possible to answer the question without knowing

Comment: Yes, I have installed WooCommerce and I have the necessary code that I said in the description. By default, WordPress allows authors to see all products in all products of your site. This can be problematic if you invite a large number of guest writers. How to limit access to all WordPress products to the user's own uploads?

I want a code to enter in the skin editor!!

Comment: you should ask this in a WooCommerce community, questions about 3rd party plugins are offtopic here and not in this stacks scope